# AES CTR mode encryption of a large zero block - sequence repeated

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm trying to use AES encryption in CTR mode and encrypt one megabyte of zeroes at once. I noticed that encrypted result is repeated every 8 kilobytes.
I.e. the output is:

```
buffer+0x0000:  0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36
....
buffer+0x2000:  0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36
....
buffer+0x4000:  0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36
```

Before I successfully used OpenSSL and Crypto++, but that new proprietary FIPS validated library looks very suspicious...

Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

experimentally I found that this lib encrypts only by 8k portions. Then I must change the counter myself.
Well, big multi-million companies can afford that!